# Proving two functions with independent variables are constant when inside an equation with isolated variables

Tags: derivatives

So I've got: $\frac{1}{r}\frac{du}{dr}=\frac{1}{2\mu}\frac{dp}{dx}$ as an equation in a fluid mechanics book. The book stipulates that if we have a function that only depends on r ont he left side and that only depends on x on the right side ($\mu$ is constant) then both functions have to be constant (I'm supposing here that means $\frac{1}{r}\frac{du}{dr}$ and $\frac{dp}{dx}$ are constant).

Is it possible to prove this? My take on it is:

We suppose that one function isn't constant (which in turn means the other isn't constant either): and so there exist two couples ($x_1$,$x_2$) and ($r_1$,$r_2$) in the respective domains of definition of both functions, so that: 
$$
\frac{1}{r_1}\frac{du}{dr}(r_1)\neq\frac{1}{r_2}\frac{du}{dr}(r_2)\space and\space \frac{dp}{dx}(x_1)\neq\frac{dp}{dx}(x_2)
$$
Yet, $\frac{1}{r}\frac{du}{dr}(r)=\frac{1}{2\mu}\frac{dp}{dx}(x)$ for every ($x$,$r$) couple in the domain of definition of the two functions respectively.

So, $\frac{1}{r_1}\frac{du}{dr}(r_1)=\frac{1}{2\mu}\frac{dp}{dx}(x_1)=\frac{1}{2\mu}\frac{dp}{dx}(x_2)$, which leads us to the contradiction.

However I am unsure that I can say that the equation means that for every ($x$,$r$) couple it is true and go onfrom there. If I cannot then is there another way to prove that the two functions are constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only write $\frac{du}{dr}$ if we know that $u$ is a differentiable function with *no variables other than* (*possibly*) $r$. Consequently, $\frac{du}{dr}$ will also be a function with no variables other than (possibly) $r$, and so will $\frac1r\frac{du}{dr}$.

By the same token, we can conclude (since $\mu$ is a constant) that $\frac1{2\mu}\frac{dp}{dx}$ is a function with no variables other than (possibly) $x$. Since these two functions are equal, then they have no variables *at all*, and so are constant.

Comment: Works for my case; in this problem the functions only have one variable, r or x respectively. Many thanks!